# Salesforce Files - Integration related queries

Tags: attachment, files

While Salesforce is pushing adoption of Salesforce Files, here are few questions from an integration product point of view:

1. Is it mandatory to convert older attachments to files?
2. What is new object type of Files to create/read them via SOAP APIs (for 
   attachments, it used to be `sobject.setType("Attachment")`)?
3. Given there are privacy/sharing possibilities with Files, how should default values be handled (want them to similar to what attachments used to have)? For example, showing attachments to only users with access to Case.
4. Is there a possibility of Salesforce customers/orgs keeping attachments and files both in their org (need to know from integration stand point of view or if movement to Files rules out backward compatibility with older attachments)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Is it mandatory to convert older attachments to files?

> There are many [good features](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_differences.htm&type=5) not available in attachment which
>   are in file. It is good to migrate your attachment to Files.

2. What is new object type of Files to create/read them via SOAP APIs
   (for attachments, it used to be sobject.setType("Attachment"))?

There are multiple object comes in picture when you say file. They are:-

- [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm):- Represents a specific version of a document in Salesforce CRM Content or Salesforce Files.
- [ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm):- Represents a document that has been uploaded to a library in Salesforce CRM Content or Salesforce Files.
- [ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm):- Represents the link between a Salesforce CRM Content document or Salesforce file and where it's shared. A file can be shared with other users, groups, records, and Salesforce CRM Content libraries.

3.Given there are privacy/sharing possibilities with Files, how should default values be handled (want them to similar to what attachments used to have)? For example, showing attachments to only users with access to Case.

> There is one field called SharingPrivacy on ContentVersion object which Controls sharing
>   privacy for a file. Only administrators and file owners with
>   Collaborator access to the file can modify this field. Default is
>   Visible to Anyone With Record Access. When set to Private on Records,
>   the file is private on records but can be shared selectively with
>   others.

4. Is there a possibility of Salesforce customers/orgs keeping attachments and files both in their org (need to know from integration stand point of view or if movement to Files rules out backward compatibility with older attachments)?

> They can co-exist as well. As a practise, Once you have migrated to
>   Files, You can keep attachment for sometime as an backup to get
>   confirmed that every attachment is migrated to files successfully.

Comment: Thanks @sanket for the information. Appreciate it.